# Url is case sensitive for action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are using simple forms authentication on our website

```
 </authentication>     
   <forms name=".CXqJkTcZWBHJ" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain=".mydomain.com" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Now I have an MVC action which can be called by an outside program.  For this action, I do not want to require authentication.
Which works when we call it: http:dev.mydomain.com/AgencyService/GetAgent/0001800
But redirect to the login page if the "AgencyService" part in the url above is typed in any other case such as: http:dev.mydomain.com/agencyservice/GetAgent/0001800

Any ideas why?

I ruled out Routes because this way also works: http:dev.mydomain.com/AgencyService/GetAgent?agencyid=0001800
And this way also doesn't work: http:dev.mydomain.com/agencyservice/GetAgent?agencyid=0001800

NOTE: I repaced my domain name above with 'mydomain' to hide my domain for this post.

Comment: Can you post your routes from your `Global.asax.cs`?

Comment: Although your example doesn't indicate you're specifying any `path` for the forms auth cookie, cookie paths *are* case sensitive. So if you had a cookie path of, say */getagent*, it would exhibit this behaviour if the user visited */GetAgent*.

Answer (score 0):

In our AuthorizeRequest sub we had a whitelist that we were comparing but not with the StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.  Once I added this it fixed the issue.